# lua if condition with "does not contain" sting

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a nginx configuration where with Lua code I want to block all domain except one(`example.com`). Since I am using Azure, I could not get just domain value from the IDToken so I am using emails(`ajay@example.com` since email also contains domain name).

Requirement is to block all access if the user email does not contain the string `example.com`
This is what I have so far but it does not have **does not contain string**

```
if res.id_token.email ~= 'example.com' then
  ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

it blocks all emails with `example.com`

since email can be anything and its a string that should use "CONTAINS", so its failing. What will be the solution for **if condition with does not contain example.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a presumably more efficient alternative to `string.match`, you can also use [`string.find`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find) (which returns indices, thus not having to build a match string), and also allows disabling pattern matching:

```lua
if not res.id_token.email:find("@example.com", 1, true) then
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

Note that your question asks for *contains*, not *ends with*.

Comment: This will not-block `blah@example.com.au` etc. Would be more precise, and still-more efficient, to [check the end of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312060/761202) since that’s the only place it can occur and be valid… :D

Comment: @AD7six The question asks for "contains" in the title, so I've implemented contains, not "ends with". See shingo's answer for an implementation of "ends with".

Comment: Indeed - I linked to it in my comment. I think this answer is too focused on the wording of the question and not the problem the op is trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This is the length of `@example.com`

```
#'@example.com'
```

Get the suffix of email with the length of `@example.com`

```
res.id_token.email:sub(-#'@example.com')
```

Compare with `@example.com`

```
res.id_token.email:sub(-#'@example.com') ~= '@example.com'
```

Comment: so the statement becomes :

`if res.id_token.email:sub(-#'@example.com') ~= '@example.com' then
  ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end` ?

Comment: The above statement is NOT working in the nginx configuration and nginx is rejecting it.

Comment: What did you mean reject it? Any error message?

Comment: The question says "contains", not "ends with".

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
if not string.match(res.id_token.email, "@example.com") then
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

Found that `string.match` can find a string to match and I have added a `not` before it.

Comment: This won't work as you expected, you should use `"@example%.com$"`. A dot `.` represents any characters and it doesn't check whether it is the suffix of a string, so an email like `xyz@example_com.org` or `xyz@example.com.org` can also pass this test.